# Select all text between quotes in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

I had to reinstall VS Code recently, I rember using Ctrl+W to kind of smart select everything between quotes but now what that command does is move me to another file/tab instead? Is there a way to do this in VS Code, Ctrl+W was just so easy to me, really helped with deleting or copying strings of text.

Comment: have you used the `Select By` extension with a key binding to `ctrl-W`

Comment: link to extension?

Comment: Shift+Alt+RightArrow

Comment: Is there any solution to select text between quotes with mouse click in VS Code?

Answer (score 30):

As @Mark says in the comment, you can use the "Expand Selection" shortcut, this will first select everything between the quotes.

The shortcut on Windows by default:
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

And OS X:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

Comment: This does not "select everything between the quotes". It selects the next "word" to the right of the cursor.

Comment: You're right, the behavior depends on where you cursor is and if a word is already selected or not. Doing it once will select the next word, and doing it a second time will select everything between the quotes.

Comment: "doing it a second time will select everything between the quotes." is only true if the cursor starts on the first character in the quotes and there are only two words inside the quotes. Without an extension, this just advances the selection one word at a time.

Comment: Are you talking of Shift + Ctrl + arrow? Because the shortcut is with Alt.
Actually I did some test, and this is only working if VS Code recognize the text as a programming language (shown in the bottom left). It's behaving differently for plain text for example.

Comment: No, I'm definitely using shift + alt + left or right arrow on files that VS Code recognizes as Ruby and Javascript. This command seems to be the same as the default selection behavior for most text editors (not just VS Code). Are you using an extension or setting that changes the behavior? Perhaps a language-specific extension? For me, plain text and recognized programming language files behave the same.

Comment: I tried with no extension and it does work at least for Javascript, Typescript and JSON, but not with Ruby. It seems the behavior depends on the language?
The shortcut is called "Expand Selection" btw, to make sure we're talking about the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for testing, confirming, and finding the name of the shortcut. On my fresh install of VS Code on OS X, the "Expand Selection" shortcut is Ctrl + Shift + Command + Right Arrow. That key combination works correctly.

Comment: Thankyou,  since adding a mac to my arsenal, Ive been looking for a way to reproduce this windows behaviour.

Answer (score 18):

Try using the `Quick and Simple Text Selection` extension.

On a Mac, the extension's default shortcut is `⌘` `k`, `"`

1. Press `⌘` and `k`
2. let go of of `⌘` and `k`
3. press `"`

This will select everything in double quotes.

If you want to select everything in single quotes use `⌘` `k`, `'`

It also works for brackets and back ticks

- `⌘` `k`, `[`
- `⌘` `k`, `{`
- `⌘` `k`, `(`
- `⌘` `k`, `<`
- `⌘` `k`, `` ` ``

On Windows, replace `⌘` with `Ctrl`

https://github.com/dbankier/vscode-quick-select

Answer (score 9):

The best / simplest way to do it I've found on Mac is to click the text anywhere in the quote marks, then hold down Control + Shift and tap the right arrow twice.

Answer (score 7):

Shift + Alt + (Right Arrow) for the word next to cursor
Shift + Alt + (Right Arrow)x2 for entire sentence between quotes

Answer (score 2):

After re-reading your question, I noticed that you want to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to press multiple times to expand your selection

To see and set the shortcut, you can

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Go to Keyboard Shortcuts by typing `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts`

   - [image]
3. Search for the command: `editor.action.smartSelect.expand`
4. Double click the keybinding to set a new keybinding

   - [image]

### Summary of answers

- Most use cases: use [@colinD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68742692/8479344) (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>← or →</kbd>) which expands the selection word by word
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> multiple times to expand the selection's scope

  - it might be different on Windows
- If you want to select all of the text in quotes and there's a lot of spaces and your cursor is in the middle of the quotes

  - Use the [Quick and Simple Text Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67065698/8479344) extension

Answer (score -1):

The quick and simple text selection does not account for escaped quotes.  So if you have "Hello "World"" and your cursor is on Hello, it will only select to the quote preceding World.