# Can you mark something from every line inside a '

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can you mark something from every line inside a ' if that didnt make any sense then i have a picture that hopefully give more sense [I want to mark everything that is inside the blue lines and inside the '](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zQNb.png)

Comment: This is a duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61180297/select-all-text-between-quotes-in-vs-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select all text between quotes in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61180297/select-all-text-between-quotes-in-vs-code)