# How to disable highlight of full string in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, highlight, double-click

I have an issue with  double clicking and highlighting in VS Code  (v 1.71.2).

Sometimes the double-click does not select the word double-clicked.

In [this screen recording](https://recordit.co/O6kdULayjX) you can see the issue:

- Every time I used a double click.
- First time the word "Condition" was not selected, but the whole string literal.
- Then it was selected but the whole line was highlighted and when copying, only "Condition" would be pasted. That is correct.

The time that the word "Condition" was colored in fuchsia is the correct one but I want only that word to be highlighted instead of the entire string.

Anyone know the setting for this?

Answer (score 1):

I concluded that the issue was that the string was highlighted due to the cursor being placed somewhere inside the string.

To disable this, I disabled the Occurrences Highlight ("editor.occurrencesHighlight": false)

By doing so, the editor did not highlight open/closing tags though.
The (partial) solution to this was to install the extension Highlight Matching Tag

Answer (score 0):

This issue was reported and fixed already, see:

- [Double Clicking On A Word Does Select The Entire String, Not Just The Word · Issue #125052 · microsoft/vscode · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125052)

Try to re-install the [version `1.71.2` for release "August 2022 Recovery 2"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases/tag/1.71.2) and see if double-click selection works as expected.

Note that different click-counts have different outcomes:

- double-click should select the word (using configured *word-separators*)
- triple-click should select the entire string
- quadruple-click should select the entire text

Configure word-separators with property `editor.wordSeparators` from preferences: [Visual Studio Code—Customizing word separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632351/visual-studio-code-customizing-word-separators)

See also related: [Double-click to select text does not always work · Issue #84319 · microsoft/vscode · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84319).

To have finer control over selecting text you can use keyboard shortcuts like explained in [Select all text between quotes in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61180297/select-all-text-between-quotes-in-vs-code).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It made me realize that this color is the "selectionHighlightBackground" which I knew, but did not realize it also highlights on simple click (where the cursor is). 
Do you know if I can disable this?

Comment: Occurrences Highlight is changing this behavior but by disabling it, it stops form highlighting open/closing tags. I guess I'll have to live with one (highlighting strings) or the other (not matching tags) as I don't see a separate setting.